# PLSQL getting value of property in record dynamically?

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, plsql, plsqldeveloper

First of all I am really rusty on Oracle PLSQL, and I have seen several folks say this cannot be done and others that say it can, and I am just not able to make it happen. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to read the value of a column in a record type dynamically.

I have a message with tokens and I need to replace the tokens with value from the record set.

So the message looks like: [status] by [agent_name]

I have another place where I am parsing out the tokens.

In java script I know this can be accomplished with: (Will run in Console)

```
var record = {
    status : "Open",
    agent_name : "John"
};

var record2 = {
    status : "Close",
    agent_name : "Joe"
};
var records = [record, record2];

var token1 = "status";
var token2 = "agent_name";



for( var i=0; i<records.length; i++){
    console.log(records[i][token1] + " by " + records[i][token2]);
}


Results : Open by John
          Close by Joe
```

I want to do the same thing in PLSQL

Here is my test PLSQL:

```
   SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
declare 

  TYPE my_record is RECORD
    (
      status         VARCHAR2(30),
      agent_name     varchar2(30)
    );  

  TYPE my_record_array IS VARRAY(6) OF my_record;   
  v_records            my_record_array := my_record_array();
  v_current_rec        my_record;
  v_current_rec2        my_record;
  v_token               varchar2(50):= 'agent_name';
  v_token2              varchar2(50):= 'status';

begin

  v_current_rec.status := 'Open';
  v_current_rec.agent_name := 'John';
  v_records.extend;
  v_records(1) := v_current_rec;

  v_current_rec2.status := 'Close';
  v_current_rec2.agent_name := 'Ron';
  v_records.extend;
  v_records(2) := v_current_rec2;

  FOR i IN 1..v_records.COUNT LOOP
      --Hard coded
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_records(i).status ||  ' by ' || v_records(i).agent_name);

      --Substitution vars entering v_records(i).status and v_records(i).agent_name for the prompts.
      --How to do this without user interaction.
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(&status ||  ' by ' || &agent_name);

      --Dynamically that doesn't work. How would this be accomplished
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_records(i).v_token ||  ' by ' || v_records(i).v_token2);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I tried using substitution variables, and that will work if I use:

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(&agent_name) and entering v_records(i).agent_name when prompted. How do I accomplish this on the fly?

ANSWER:

```
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE
type sr_record_map
 IS
  TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);


 type record_set 
 is
 TABLE of  sr_record_map index by BINARY_INTEGER; 

  v_current_rec             sr_record_map;
  v_record_set              record_set;
  v_token                   varchar2(30) := 'status';
  v_token2                  varchar2(30) := 'agent_name';

  v_index                   number :=1;

 begin 
v_current_rec('status') := 'Open';
v_current_rec('agent_name') := 'John';
v_record_set(1) := v_current_rec;

v_current_rec('status') := 'Close';
v_current_rec('agent_name') := 'Joe';
v_record_set(2) := v_current_rec;

FOR i in 1..v_record_set.COUNT LOOP
    v_current_rec := v_record_set(i);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_current_rec(v_token) || ' by ' || v_current_rec(v_token2));
END LOOP;
end;
```

Comment: You say, your record may have any members (columns) and you want to print them by choosing one ?

Comment: I have multiple message that may have any number of tokens. I know the fields exist in the record. So if I have a token agent_name I want to eval the string v_records(i).agent_name and get the value from the record. So I can replace the token in the message with the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an [ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#CHDEIDIC) just like Maps in Java

```
DECLARE
type my_record_map
IS
  TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(30);
type my_record
IS
  record
  (
    my_members my_record_map );
type final_map
IS
  TABLE OF my_record INDEX BY VARCHAR2(20);
  v_final_map final_map;
  v_my_record_map my_record_map;
  v_my_record my_record;
  index_name VARCHAR2(100);
  index_name_record VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  /* Individual Records as key value pairs with their Corresponding Columns */
  /* You can put any member name inside */

  v_my_record_map('status')     := 'Open';
  v_my_record_map('agent_name') := 'John';
  v_my_record_map('added_by') := 'Maheshwaran';


  /* Put it as a record */
  v_my_record.my_members := v_my_record_map;

  /* Put the record inside Another Map with any Key */
  v_final_map('Record1')     := v_my_record;


  v_my_record_map('status')     := 'Close';
  v_my_record_map('agent_name') := 'Joe';
  v_my_record_map('added_by') := 'Ravisankar';

  v_my_record.my_members := v_my_record_map;

  v_final_map('Record2')     := v_my_record;

  /* Take the First Key in the Outer most Map */
  index_name         := v_final_map.FIRST;
  LOOP
    /* status Here can be dynamic */
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(CHR(10)||'######'||v_final_map(index_name).my_members('status') ||' by '||v_final_map(index_name).my_members('agent_name')||'######'||CHR(10));

    index_name_record := v_final_map(index_name).my_members.FIRST;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('$ Ávailable Other Members + Values.. $'||CHR(10));
    LOOP
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('     '||index_name_record ||'='||v_final_map(index_name).my_members(index_name_record));
       index_name_record := v_final_map(index_name).my_members.NEXT(index_name_record);
       EXIT WHEN index_name_record IS NULL;
    END LOOP;
    /* Next gives you the next key */
    index_name := v_final_map.NEXT(index_name);
    EXIT WHEN index_name IS NULL;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
######Open by John######

$ Ávailable Other Members + Values.. $

     added_by=Maheshwaran
     agent_name=John
     status=Open

######Close by Joe######

$ Ávailable Other Members + Values.. $

     added_by=Ravisankar
     agent_name=Joe
     status=Close
```

Comment: This is it. Will post answer in my question for this example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can be done with a record type. It may be possible with an object type since you could query the fields from the data dictionary, but there isn't normally anywhere those are available (though there's an 11g facility called [PL/Scope](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/whatsnew.htm#LNPLS125) that might allow it if it's enabled).

Since you're defining the record type in the same place you're using it, and if you have a manageable number of fields, it might be simpler to just try to replace each token, which just (!) wastes a bit of CPU if one doesn't exist in the message:

```
declare 

  TYPE my_record is RECORD
    (
      status         VARCHAR2(30),
      agent_name     varchar2(30)
    );  

  TYPE my_record_array IS VARRAY(6) OF my_record;   
  v_records            my_record_array := my_record_array();
  v_current_rec        my_record;
  v_current_rec2       my_record;
  v_message            varchar2(50):= '[status] by [agent_name]';
  v_result             varchar2(50);
begin

  v_current_rec.status := 'Open';
  v_current_rec.agent_name := 'John';
  v_records.extend;
  v_records(1) := v_current_rec;

  v_current_rec2.status := 'Close';
  v_current_rec2.agent_name := 'Ron';
  v_records.extend;
  v_records(2) := v_current_rec2;

  FOR i IN 1..v_records.COUNT LOOP
      v_result := v_message;
      v_result := replace(v_result, '[agent_name]', v_records(i).agent_name);
      v_result := replace(v_result, '[status]', v_records(i).status);
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_result);      
  END LOOP;
END;
/

anonymous block completed
Open by John
Close by Ron
```

It needs to be maintained of course; if a field is added to the record type than a matching `replace` will need to be added to the body.

I assume in the real world the message text, complete with tokens, will be passed to a procedure. I'm not sure it's worth parsing out the tokens though, unless you need them for something else.

Comment: We came up with something similar, but basically trying to make this so that it is dynamic, so that we can add data to the record that we are sending into the procedure and then insert new tokens into the message. This proc would get a record set and a message. Creating an "auto" mapping to the columns in the record.

Comment: @John - as long as there is one `replace` for each field in the record, I'm unclear what making it dynamic would achieve. You can't add a new token to the message unless the field is defined in the record anyway? Maybe you don't really want a record collection at all, but an associative array if the fields needs to change at run-time?

Comment: This is just prototype. The Type is actually defined some where else. I am trying to minimize the points of change. We have several  procs that are going to sending record sets into this proc. I want to prevent having to change this every time the the other procs change.

Comment: @John - you'd only have to change this when the type changed, not the callers. Where is the type defined; is your real type actually a record type (defined in a package, say), or is it an object type defined at schema level? I don't think you can do it with a record type. You can get the field names from PL/Scope and loop over them, but I don't think there's a way to reference them dynamically. (Even with a dynamic SQL hack; you can't pass a record as a bind variable - PLS-00457).

Answer (score 0):

As an example, I'm attaching simple code by which you can dynamically compare any two records of any table by name of table and id values, to get differences in data..

```
DECLARE 

p_id_1 NUMBER DEFAULT 697403;
p_id_2 NUMBER DEFAULT 697402;
p_table_name VARCHAR2(200) DEFAULT 'Name of the table';
V_result_1 VARCHAR2(2000);
V_result_2 VARCHAR2(2000);

CURSOR cur IS 
SELECT * FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE table_name = p_table_name ;

BEGIN

FOR rec IN cur LOOP

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
       'SELECT ' || rec.COLUMN_NAME || ' FROM '  || P_TABLE_NAME ||
       ' WHERE ID = :1 '
       INTO V_result_1
       USING P_ID_1
       ; 

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
       'SELECT ' || rec.COLUMN_NAME || ' FROM '  || P_TABLE_NAME ||
       ' WHERE ID = :1 '
       INTO V_result_2
       USING P_ID_2
       ; 

IF NVL(v_result_1, 0) <> NVL(v_result_2,0) THEN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Column_name ' || rec.column_name || ' ' || v_result_1 || '\' || v_result_2);
END IF; 

END LOOP;

END;
```